# How can I use Intellij Structural Search to find all methods that use two named classes?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

Say I have two Java classes, TradeType and InstrumentType.  I know that somewhere in my codebase there is a method that maps from TradeType to InstrumentType.

How can I use Structural Search in Intellij to say

"find me all methods that have a single parameter of type TradeType and which return InstrumentType"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Search template:

```
class $Class$ { 
    InstrumentType $MethodName$(TradeType $Parameter$);
}
```

Then click `Edit variables...`, and set the following for the `MethodName` variable:

- Occurrences count: Unlimited
- This variable is target of the search

Also pay attention to what the scope of the search is.

Comment: This was really helpful to get me started with structural search. The docs just weren't all that useful