# Structural Search to match method call with generic parameter

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

Let's say that I have a class `class Foo : Base` and I want to perform a certain method call with signature

```
public void someStuf(Iterable<? extends Base> param)
```

For the search template I just take as starting point the *pre-existing* one

```
$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)
```

Is it possible to match a parameter of any *kind* `Iterable` of a specific `Base` subclass (`Foo` in this example)??

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
fooList.add(new Foo("A"));
List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();
barList.add(new Bar(1));

someStuff(fooList); // find this!
someStuff(barList); // don't find this one
someStuff(Collections.singletonList(new Foo("B"))); // also match this one
```

I've tried several combinations without any luck, is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was previously not possible without resorting to a hack. See further below for that. Currently, the code can be found using a Type modifier.

#### search template

```
$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)
```

#### variables

`$Instance$` Count=`[0,1]`
`$MethodCall` Text=`someStuff`
`$Parameter$` Type=`Iterable<Foo>, within type hierarchy`

#### hack

The hack previously needed used a Script modifier and a simple Type modifier on the `$Parameter$` variable:

`$Parameter$`
Script=`__context__.type.parameters[0].presentableText.contains("Foo")`
Type=`Iterable`

The related [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178118) is fixed since IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.

Comment: Thanks you very much!